# specs2 html output in travis

Tags: travis-ci, pandoc, specs2

My `build.sbt` contains dependencies

```
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.8.9" % "test",
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-html" % "3.8.9" % "test",
```

and also

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("html", "console")
```

When I run locally, HTML output is generated.

In `.travis.yml` I declare:

```
addons:
  apt_packages:
    - pandoc

script:
  - sbt test
```

Builds on Travis fail with:

```
[error] pandoc: Unknown reader: markdown+pipe_tables+auto_identifiers+header_attributes+inline_code_attributes+markdown_attribute
```

Here is a minimal replication of the issue:

- [github repo](https://github.com/Synesso/travis-specs2-html/)
- [travis-ci build](https://travis-ci.org/Synesso/travis-specs2-html)

How can I configure Travis's pandoc to include these readers?

Comment: I don't know which pandoc version you get via apt. Could it be a problem similar to this one? https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/751

Comment: I had the same thought. I'm currently trying to figure out how to install pandoc with cabal on travis.

Comment: I'm trying different ways to install pandoc, but I can't run apt-get without `sudo: true`, but if I set sudo on, sbt no longer works.

Comment: try the [pandoc debian package](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.19.2.1). if you have to build from source I recommend `stack` over `cabal`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis' default Ubuntu dist (Precise) does not have access to version of pandoc recent enough to handle markdown.

It is necessary to specify a more recent dist (Trusty).

```
dist: trusty

addons:
  apt_packages:
    - pandoc
```